# Android UI Design : viewpager inside coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to make awesome design like this.
but I have some questions about making it.

1. Is it using coordinatorlayout? If is so, How can I put fragment inside it like this?
2. How can I stack cards when using viewpager? (it doesn't have to be viewpager, just want to know how)

[image]